# Unable to install any application. While installing language pack it throws error

Tags: package-management, language-support

```
Lenovo-G570:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
[sudo] password for parmeet: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
language-pack-en is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 128 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

parmeet@parmeet-Lenovo-G570:~$
```

and the etc/environment file is:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/home/parmeet/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_20/bin
```

Comment: language-pack-en is already the newest version.

Comment: It says there is some kind of syntax error in your `/etc/environment` file. Can you please edit your question and show us the contents of that file?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f` However `language-pack-en is already the newest version.`!

Answer (score 3):

The line `/etc/environment: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching "'` in the error message says that you missed a double quote `"` at the end of the second line.

Change the second line from

`JAVA_HOME="/home/parmeet/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_20/bin`

to

`JAVA_HOME="/home/parmeet/JAVA/jdk1.8.0_20/bin"`

and try `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en` again